# How to get EditText values and show them as a html file in a Web view?

Tags: android

How I can get the EditText values and show values as a html file in a Web view?  Please help me. Very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any file if what you want is to show the value in the WebView. Use:

```
mWebView.loadData("<html><body>text: <b>" + mEditText.getText().toString() + "</b></body></html>", "text/html", null);
```